# libffmpeg.so Not Executing ffmpeg 2.8.4 Commands

Tags: android, ffmpeg

- libffmpeg.so is not working with command line arguments
- I have successfully compiles ffmpeg and get static libffmpeg.so library.
- I installed using android.mk and its installed successfully
- but unable to execute ffmpeg command.

  ```
  *My build.sh is as follows 
  function build_r8b_test
  {
  bash configure --target-os=linux \
  --arch=arm \
  --cpu=cortex-a8 \
  --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
  --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --enable-pic \
  --disable-shared \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-cross-compile \
  --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
  --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --sysroot="$PLATFORM" \
  --extra-cflags="-I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fPIE -pie -fPIC -DANDROID -marm -march=armv7-" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L../x264 -L$PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9" \
  --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-version3 \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --disable-doc \
  --enable-yasm \
  --enable-decoders \
  --enable-encoders \
  --enable-muxers \
  --enable-demuxers \
  --enable-parsers \
  --enable-protocols \
  --enable-filters \
  --disable-indevs \
  --disable-outdevs \
  --enable-hwaccels \
  --disable-ffmpeg \
  --disable-ffplay \
  --disable-ffprobe \
  --disable-ffserver \
  --disable-network \
  --enable-zlib \
  --enable-demuxer=mov \
  --enable-demuxer=h264 \
  --enable-protocol=file \
  --enable-avformat \
  --enable-avcodec \
  --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
  --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
  --enable-decoder=h263 \
  --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
  --enable-decoder=h264 \
  --enable-parser=h264 \
  --enable-encoder=mpeg4 \
  --disable-asm \
  --enable-neon \
  --enable-armv5te \
  --disable-network \
  --enable-avfilter \
  --disable-avdevice \
  --enable-postproc \

  $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
  make clean
  make
  make  -j4 install
  $PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-          link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libavfilter/libavfilter.a libpostproc/libpostproc.a libswresample/libswresample.a libswscale/libswscale.a   -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-search-mismatch  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/libgcc.a
  }
  #arm v7vfpv3
  CPU=armv7-a
  OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=$CPU "
  PREFIX=./android/$CPU
  ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
  build_r8b_test

  * and my androi.mk is as follow
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
  APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE =myffmpeg
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=libffmpeg.so
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  PATH_TO_FFMPEG_SOURCE:=$(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg
  LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(PATH_TO_FFMPEG_SOURCE)
  LOCAL_MODULE=ffmpeg-jni
  LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/home/admin/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib -L$(LOCAL_PATH) -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -ldl -lgcc -lm
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg-jni.c ffmpeg/cmdutils.h ffmpeg/cmdutils.c ffmpeg/ffmpeg.h ffmpeg/ffmpeg_opt.c ffmpeg/ffmpeg_filter.c

  LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:=myffmpeg
  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
  ```

  - I have successfully installed armeabi obj and armeabi-v7a 
    But it is not works simple ffmpeg command like (ffmpeg -y -i /mnt/sdcard/app.mp4 /mnt/sdcard/app.mkv).
    Applciation is terminate at  ret = ffmpeg_parse_options(argc, argv); in ffmpeg-jni.c 
    which is copied from ffmpeg.c.
    If i am doing wrond build please help me to get out this.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: hi Mustansar Saeed.thanks for you reply.
I am not getting any error but command which i pass to jni file is not work.
while c function is called in ffmpeg-jni.c it's terminates at some line of code.
in video_merge(int argc, char **argv) function it is terminate at line 
 ret = ffmpeg_parse_options(argc, argv); 
and not returning any value

Comment: you must comment `exit()` out